# Using BigM equations to minimize a variable

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, minimization

I am trying to minimize the following equation:

`P_ch_max = min(22, E_need*m_int) where E_need*m_int` can be bigger or lower than 22 depending on the data.

I am using the following equations in `pyomo` to do it:

```
m.C6 = ConstraintList()
for t in m.ts2:
    m.C6.add(expr = m.char_power - m.var_E_need[0,t]*m_int  <= 100*m.Y[t])
    m.C6.add(expr = m.var_E_need[0,t]*m_int - m.char_power <= 100 * (1-m.Y[t]))
    m.C6.add(expr = m.var_P_ch_max[0,t] <= m.var_E_need[0,t]*m_int  )
    m.C6.add(expr = m.var_P_ch_max[0,t]  <= m.char_power)
    m.C6.add(expr = m.var_P_ch_max[0,t] >= m.var_E_need[0,t]*m_int - 100*(1-m.Y[t]))
    m.C6.add(expr = m.var_P_ch_max[0,t]  >= m.char_power - 100*m.Y[t])
```

`m.char_power = 22; m.Y` is a `boolean;` 100 is my big` in this case

When I substitute the values of Y manually, these equations make sense:
When `Y=0` I get that `P_ch_max<= 22` and `P_ch_max>= 22` which would make `P_ch_max == 22`.
When `Y=1` I get that `P_ch_max<= E_need*m_int` and `P_ch_max>= E_need*m_int` which would make `P_ch_max = E_need*m_int`.

However, when I run the code in `pyomo` it says it's unfeasible or unbounded and I don't understand why. Is there any other way to do this? Or can you tell me if I am doing something wrong pls?

Comment: You don't show all of your code...  Your problem might be in your objective function if you are using `min()` which is non-linear and cannot be used in a pyomo expression.

Comment: I am not using min() in my objective function! its simply just: 
m.obj = Objective(expr = sum_bids_V1G, sense=maximize)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to unwind your equations and figure out why it is infeasible.  But you can do a couple things rather quickly to tackle this.

First, you can start to "comment out" constraints and see if you can get the model breathing (such that the solver doesn't complain about infeasibility), and then investigate from there.

Second, if you think you know a feasible solution (as you suggest in your comment about plugging in), then just plug in your values by assigning them and then `display` your model and it should stand out very quickly which constraints are violated.  For example:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.x = pyo.Var()

m.c1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=m.x >= 5)

m.x = 4

m.display()
```

#### Yields:

```
Model unknown

  Variables:
    x : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :  None :     4 :  None : False : False :  Reals

  Objectives:
    None

  Constraints:
    c1 : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :   5.0 :    4 :  None
[Finished in 210ms]
```